# Unexpected token ILLEGAL with gzip compression

Tags: javascript, compression, gzip, runtime-error, deflate

I am having a problem with gzip compression on my site.  I've combined several javascript files to one files and they work ok without compression. Afterwards I've compressed them (gzip) and tried to run the site again, but get the following error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

I've compressed the file using several methods, one using gzip software and I also tried other gzip online compression tools [like this one](http://www.refresh-sf.com/yui/).

I can't understand why I get this error why it doesn't work, because the non-compressed version does work. I ran the site on Chrome, latest version.

It also tells me that the error is in line 1

> all_js.js.gz:1

Of course the compressed code has many lines, not just one.

I've read a few answers, but nothing regarding gzip compression.

I get this error when working with Visual Studio (ASP.NET) on local machine.

I tried serving the file from S3 with 'application/x-gzip' headers, but it still didn't work. I want to serve my files via CDN after compressing, so I don't search for server compression solutions.

Comment: Are you sure that your server is setting the headers appropriately so that the client knows the content is zipped?

Comment: no, I am not sure. I am testing it locally. I am working with ASP.net, anything I need to make it work. I also tried submitting it to Amazon S3 and it still didn't work (application/x-gzip)

Comment: OK, well it's not set up correctly from that Amazon link. The content type must be "text/javascript", and there has to be another header for the encoding. I'm not 100% sure how to do that but there are many guides about serving pre-compressed static content.

Comment: Pointy, you were correct. I've setup two header text/javascript for 'content-type' and gzip for 'content-encoding' - it works!!

Answer (score -8):

You cannot compress a javascript file with gzip or any other zip routine and load it into your webpage.

You can do one of two things:

- Use a javascript code compression tool like the [YUI compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/).
- Configure your webserver to compress the files (please read the documentation of your webserver, it should not be very difficult)

Comment: But I did it on other websites and it worked. I compressed and upload to CDN and current sites does work with gzip file, and it appears as j.gzip in the js source file as well. Maybe I remember wrong, I will try the YUI and tell you how it went.

Comment: This answer is not correct. [It is quite possible to serve pre-compressed static content.](http://goo.gl/h08FE)

Comment: Pointy, you are absolutely right, it is possible, but it depends on you webserver configuration (or CDN configuration).